# Powershell command from cmd doesnt replace line breaks

Tags: shell, powershell, cmd

I am trying to replace a string including a line break in a file. I am using the command line for this.

I am trying to use the same command in a CMD shell and in PowerShell, however I can only seem to get it to work in the latter.

Here is the command:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content client.properties -Raw).Replace('#test`r`n','test`r`n') | Set-Content client2.properties"
```

Why is this not working in a CMD shell, and how do I make it work?

Comment: Did you run literally the exact same command in both shells, or the cmd equivalent of the powershell command?

Comment: Can you specify your problem in a more detailed way? You're writing that it works in powershell and not cmd line. Do you've to use normal WIN command line?

Comment: Ive run exactly the same command. Ive opened a cmd shell and ran it and i also tried to run it in a bat file. When i open a Powershell and run the command, it works. Im working with Win 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `` `r`n `` escape sequence won't work inside single-quotes.

Use the `-replace` operator instead and use regex escapes:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content client.properties -Raw)-replace('#test\r?\n','test'+$([Environment]::NewLine)) | Set-Content client2.properties"
```

Comment: Thanks, the line break is now recognized correctly. But the adding of the line break doesnt work. It just pastes "test\r?\n" as a String. Any idea?

Comment: Were almost there. Now i get a RuntimeException "-ireplace" only allows 2 elements, not 3. If i use only "$([Environment]::NewLine)" it works, so somehow the concatenation of test and the linebreak is wrong.

Comment: just set "()" around test and linebreak, so it wil be concatenated before added as a element to -replace

Comment: That helped. Thank you all!